# Spring boot : Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: java, html, spring

i'm new in Java  and Spring boot , i want to create  a programme that show me an HTML page,
when i use this   :

```
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>  
</dependency>
```

everything wooks good , and i'm  having the login page first , then my HTML page that i created

BUT when i remove the dependency of security ( because i don't need it  , i want to show directly my HTML page ) , it's gives me an Erros

[should i change the place of the AppController ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHmcA.png)

Comment: So, I run your code, and after removing some dependencies, it starts working. You have implemented so many dependencies which you do not need. Always add minimum dependencies that are necessary. Please post your ERROR so that I can debug what exactly causing it. If you are just starting in java and spring, try to use the in-memory database h2 and do not import any security dependencies.

Comment: are you using Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
```

Use

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
```

Comment: Why did you put repository and controller in the test src folder? This is only for tests

Comment: i put it now in the package  "com.example.TEST_WEB" , and the index page in tamplates , but still having the same prob

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: Please share Github link.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pAmwo0jkpF7RgjLUYNtZvV_A9HH1adgW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SurendraMeena YOU CAN FIND MY CODE IN THIS LINK

Comment: I'm sorry to say but your project is a mess. Why you don't start over at https://start.spring.io/ and read a tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/